# SVG clock hour hand length

Tags: css, svg, clock

I've been playing round with this clock on code pen http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/qfdne.

Can anyone help me reduce the length of the hour hand?  I've tried altering the height but it seems to be drawing the hand from the outside in.

The piece of code in question is:

```
<div id="clock-container"  style="padding-left:180px;">
<font color="white" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;London</font>
<svg id="clock" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle id="face" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"/>
  <g id="hands">
    <rect id="hour" x="47.5" y="12.5" width="5" height="40" rx="2.5" ry="2.55" />
    <rect id="min" x="48.5" y="12.5" width="3" height="40" rx="2" ry="2"/>
    <line id="sec" x1="50" y1="50" x2="50" y2="16" />
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply change both the `height` and the `y`. For example, for `20px` shorter:

```
<rect id="hour" x="47.5" y="32.5" width="5" height="20" rx="2.5" ry="2.55" />
```

The center of the clock is at `50, 50`, so the formulas for `x` and `y` for both hands are:

```
x = 50 - width/2
y = 50 - height
```